# Check the position inside the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to check the position inside the textbox by using javascript, or any kinds of javascript framework? Say, the figure 1 is at position 2 and the figure 3 is at position 3.

[image]
Figure. 1.

[image]
Figure. 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the 2 helpful methods:

```
function doGetCaretPosition (ctrl) {

    var CaretPos = 0;
    // IE Support
    if (document.selection) {

        ctrl.focus ();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();

        Sel.moveStart ('character', -ctrl.value.length);

        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;

    return (CaretPos);

}


function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos)
{

    if(ctrl.setSelectionRange)
    {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
    }
    else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Caret plugin.

```
pos = $(textarea).caret()
```

[jQuery Caret](https://github.com/accursoft/caret)